# Unable to get R script to execute second part of code to download a csv

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a script in R that will:

1. Check if a folder exists and if not, create it
2. Download a csv file from the internet and place it in the specified folder

The script executes Part 1 fine and creates the folder, however it won't execute Part 2 and download the file automatically. I have to do this manually in RStudio and it works, but I want it to run automatically

Created a script with just Part 2 and it executes fine.

```
#Create directory first

if (!file.exists("data")) {
        dir.create("data")
        }

#Download file

fileUrl <-"https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Fss06hid.csv"
download.file(fileUrl, destfile = "./data/cameras.csv")

}
```

There are no error messages, it just executes Part 1 but does not execute Part 2.

Can someone advise what I'm missing here? TIA

Comment: Your code is working perfectly on my pc, it download the .csv file just fine.

Comment: Also working perfectly fine on my computer. Maybe you have some connectivity issues.

Comment: Like Julio said maybe you have some connectivity issues. Is this your personnal computer? Seems like something outside of R prevent you from downloading the file.

Comment: Thanks it is working now. It worked in R console but not Studio but worked after restarting R Studio. Thanks all for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it is working now. It worked in R console but not Studio but worked after restarting R Studio. Thanks all for the input